# Accent problem when exporting postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, export

I'm exporting my postgresql db using the command

```
su - postgres -c "pg_dump --inserts --column-inserts mydb" > export.sql
```

But when I open the exported file with vi, the letter with accents are not being displayed correctly, however the web app that reads data from this DB does show them ok.

Any hints ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can either be due to

- Your vi is not configured to support UTF-8 characters, try to add `set fileencodings=utf-8,latin1` to your vimrc
- Your pg_dump is not dumping as UTF-8, you can force it to do so by adding `-E UTF8` to your pg_dump options

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did both: 1) created a .vimrc under /root with the fileecodings entry and 2) added the --encoding=UTF8 option and exported but no luck. Any other hints?

Comment: If you did both it should be okay, it's still showing weird characters? If so have you tried restoring the DB just to check?